# Appcelerator doesn't detect android SDK

Tags: appcelerator, genymotion, appcelerator-studio, appcelerator-cli

I have tried installing Appcelerator studio several times but no success, It doesn't detect android studio !! and displaying:

[EDIT]:  [link to jira ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3394)

```
["Expected ')'","",1]
["Expected ')'","",1]
["Unable to set property 'sdkInfo' of undefined or null reference","https://appc-studio.appcelerator.com/",198]
```

I tried to remove android sdk and install again in c:\android-sdk and I tried to reinstall JDK. I have googled for solution but nothing :-(

- Windows 7 64bit
- Android sdk
- Android ndk
- Genymotion
- node.js
- Android studio

When I try to run 'appc info' I get an error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\xxxx>appc info
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.2.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

An uncaught exception was thrown!
spawn cmd ENOENT
spawn cmd ENOENT

C:\Users\xxxx>
```

And when trying to run 'appc setup' I get the same error:

```
C:\Users\xxxx>appc setup
Finding latest version ...5.2.0 OK
Version 5.2.0 already installed.
? Do you plan on developing Titanium apps? Yes

Checking your environment...

An uncaught exception was thrown!
spawn cmd ENOENT
spawn cmd ENOENT

C:\Users\xxxx>
```

It been a while fighting to run appcelerator with no success, any help will be appreciated :-)

Comment: Try running `appc use latest`.

Comment: I tried but the same error

Comment: @user2005049 the first issue you run into is https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7458. The second is a bigger pain obviously. The second one seems like an issue with the Unified CLI calling the embedded Titanium CLI. Could you try the stand-alone Titanium CLI to see if that gives us more hints? `npm i -g titanium && ti setup`

Comment: Since this is clearly a bug (or something in your environment we could anticipate on), could you also create a [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/) ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 1):

spawn cmd ENOENT ?? I believe issue might be with your windows os environment.

For some people adding C:\Windows\System32\ to the PATH Environment helped. Give a try!